# Action within a Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Ok so I have a form like this ....

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="http://localhost/shopper/admin/index.php?route=system/template/update&amp;token=19690a8b739af0d963f129b93b236f1d&amp;template_id=22">
....
                    <span class="delete"><a href="#" class="delete_step" rel="1">Delete Step</a></span> 
                         <tr>           
                  <td><span class="required">*</span> Template Name:</td>
                  <td><input size="100" value="real" name="name"></td>
                </tr>
                                    ....

                    <span class="delete"><a href="#" class="delete_step" rel="2">Delete Step</a></span> 
                     <tr>           
              <td><span class="required">*</span> Template Name:</td>
              <td><input size="100" value="real" name="name"></td>
            </tr>   
    ....
    </form>
```

And i need it to where when someone clicks on the "delete_step" anchor tag that the page goes to a different location then where the form goes and with the data in the rel tag....I was thinking something like this approach

```
 $('.delete_step').live('click', function(e) {
   var delete_location = window.location.pathname.replace('admin/', '');            
   window.href = delete_location + '?route=module/delete_step&template_number=<?php print $template_id; ?>&step_id=' + $(this).attr("rel");
 });
```

The problem is it always goes to this location

```
  http://localhost/shopper/admin/#
```

I tried preventDefault but then nothing happens...any ideas

Answer (score 2):

Three things. First, you have a javascript error since preventing the default action did not solve your problem.  The error is when you attempt to reference the `href` property of the `window` object.  The `window` object doesn't have this property.  Just set `location.href = ...`.  Second, I would return false from the click handler since you probably want to both prevent the default action **and** prevent the click from propagating to the containing elements.  Third, I would not do a delete action using a GET request. I'd wrap it up in a form post (could be via AJAX, too) so that the user can't bookmark it and do a delete accidentally.

You can confirm the first by looking at the console in Firefox/Firebug.

```
$('.delete_step').live('click', function(e) {
   var delete_location = window.location.pathname.replace('admin/', '');
   var data = 'route=module/delete_step&template_number=<?php print $template_id; ?>&step_id=' + $(this).attr("rel");
   $.post( delete_location, data, function(result) {
        // handle the result of doing the deletion
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`window.href` should be `window.location.href`. But I would say to redirect from the server code.